# Checkbox input and php weird behavior

Tags: php, html, checkbox, input

I'm experiencing some weird issues with html checkboxes in PHP. The thing is: I have options that are checked by default with the 'checked="checked"' attribute and if I uncheck them, php still counts as a checked box.

Are there any workarounds to solve this problem?

This is what check some boxes by default:

```
<?php
foreach($User->listRanks() as $rank):
?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td width="30">
    <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($action == "edit") echo ($User->checkRank($rank->id_rank, $info->id_user_admin) > 0 ? 'checked="checked"':'');?> name="rank_item[]" value="<?php echo $rank->id_rank;?>" />
    </td>
    <td><?php echo utf8_encode($rank->title_rank);?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

This is what gets the inputs:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST["rank_item"] as $k => $v):
    $User->setRank($v, $User->getId($_POST["nick"]));
endforeach;
?>
```

If, for instance, I uncheck some of the default checked items, they would still count as checked.

EDIT: checkRank method:

```
public function checkRank($rid, $id) {
    $query = parent::query("SELECT * FROM ranks_rel WHERE id_rank = :r AND id_user_admin = :i");
    $query = parent::bind(":r", $rid);
    $query = parent::bind(":i", $id);
    $query = parent::run("rowcount");
    return $query;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Please show your CODE!

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I for one isn't telepathic and can't read minds ;-) Show your code indeed, we can't help much without it.

Comment: Added code. Sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: Are you sure that they are being counted as checked, or is it that you have a `->setRank()` method but not a `->unsetRank()` method (or other means to removed the unchecked values on the php side.

Comment: Well, I unset all the ranks before set them again. For debugging, I took the setRank method out and replaced it with echo $v so I could see what was being counted and I realised it counted both unchecked and checked inputs.

Comment: method "$User->checkRank()" is not included in your code

Comment: Snippet added. I don't think it has something to do with this method though.